# Freezing when Selecting Large Dataset in Interactive Bar + Heatmap

Tags: python, altair

Following the tutorial https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/interactive_cross_highlight.html

When I do my own data this mostly works fine, even with some tweaks.  However I have a strange case now.

When I have any individual bar grow beyond 10,000-ish in size, selecting it (either single or part of a multi select) Altair freezes. No browser crash, no hang, it just stops doing anything.

Currently I read the data to a pandas DF and pass that.  I tried to pass the CSV directly, but then I get no data at all and just empty charts for some reason.  However Im not entirely convinced the DF is the issue, as it generates the initial graph just fine. Its only when selecting a single large bar thats a problem.

Thanks!

[image: The large bar at the top representing 20,000 entries is the problem.]

EDIT :

Current attempt -

```
dh = "C:\\Path\\My.csv"
outputDH='C:\\Path\\My.html'
dh_table   = pd.read_csv(dh)

selector4 = alt.selection_multi(encodings=['y', 'color'])

bar4=alt.Chart(dh_table).mark_bar().encode(
x=alt.X('count():Q', axis=alt.Axis(title='Observation Count')),
y=alt.Y('rid:N', stack='zero', axis=alt.Axis(title='RIDs')),
color=alt.condition(selector4, 'int_source:N', alt.value('lightgray'), 
legend=alt.Legend(title='Int Source'))
).add_selection(
selector4
)


text4 = alt.Chart(dh_table).mark_text(dx=-6, dy=3, 
color='white',clip=True).encode(
x=alt.X('count(rid):Q', stack='zero'),
y=alt.Y('rid:N'),
detail='int_source:N',
text=alt.Text('count(rid):Q', format='.0f')
)

rect4 = alt.Chart(dh_table).mark_rect().encode(
alt.X('did:N', axis=alt.Axis(title='DID')),
alt.Y('directive_state:N', axis=alt.Axis(title='State')),
alt.Color('count()',
    scale=alt.Scale(scheme='blues'),
    legend=alt.Legend(title='Num Records')
)
)

circ4 = rect4.mark_point().encode(
alt.Color("d_enum:N",
    scale=alt.Scale(scheme='inferno'),
    legend=alt.Legend(title='DEnum', tickMinStep=1)
),
alt.Size('d_enum:N',
    legend=alt.Legend(title='DEnum', tickMinStep=1)
)
).transform_filter(selector4)

alt.hconcat(
(rect4+circ4).resolve_scale(color='independent'),
(bar4+text4)
).resolve_legend(
color="independent",
size="independent"
).save(outputDH)
```

Now, when I say I tried passing the CSV directly, what I mean is instead of passing the dataframe dh_table, I just passed dh.  That resulted in tables with no data. So I went back to passing the dataframe.

However, I solved it. It seems it had to do with the column actually being NULL.
For some reason, once I went through and just replaced NULL with a non-sensical ID (9999999999 for example), then the entire issue disappeared. It still takes longer than normal by a second or two, but I think thats expected with 25,000+ entries in a multi-select.

Comment: Please edit your question to add a code sample that reproduces your issue, otherwise it will be difficult to answer your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Comment: Specifically, when you say "selecting", I don't know if it's an interval selection, a multi selection, a single selection, whether it's triggering on encodings or fields or both. When you say "tried to pass the CSV directly", I have no information about *how* you passed the CSV directly. A system file path? An HTTP URL? All of that is relevant information, and nobody will be able to answer your question without it. Providing a minimal reproduction code snippet is the best way to provide those details.

Comment: I'll try to replicate it on non-real data, and will ping here once I can update with the appropriate information.  To clarify, I meant "clicking on the big bar" to update the heat map. It's set as a multi-selection, but any selection involving a bar that's over ~10-15K entires (like the "null" bar above) causes the program to hang.  This includes clicking on the bar by itself.  Any other combination of bars to update the circle+heatmap causes no issue. Will ping again once I have an example.

Comment: @jakevdp For what it's worth, I'm not sure why, but I editted the above explaining that once I removed the "null" field by simply renaming it, the problem went away. It appears it doesn't like having a "null" or "NaN" field name.